# Permission denied when trying to scrape targets with Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have Prometheus setup as a standalone service in a VM. I am able to go to *localhost:9090* and move freely through the UI - graph, status, alerts, etc. I am also able to curl the metrics page and get a list of metrics. The issue I’m having is I get a permission denied error when trying to scrape metrics from my targets (*localhost:9090/targets*), including the same Prometheus instance.

The specific error message I get is “Get “*http://localhost:9090/metrics*": dial tcp [::1]:9090: connect: permission denied”. The error shows itself in all of the surrounding services - node exporter & alertmanager.

Prometheus target error: Get "http://localhost:9090/metrics": dial tcp [::1]:9090: connect: permission denied

Node target error: Get "http://localhost:9100/metrics": dial tcp [::1]:9100: connect: permission denied

Alertmanager error: msg="Error sending alert" err="Post "http://localhost:9093/api/v2/alerts": dial tcp [::1]:9093: connect: permission denied"

Does anyone know where this error message originates from? What permissions do I not have?

Edit: I've tried opening all ports listed above.

Comment: Can you check if the mentioned services listen on ipv6 and, if applicable, whether it is allowed by firewall?

Comment: @anemyte Do you mean what configured in my _prometheus.yaml_ file? I currently have it looking at node exporter and prometheus. I've tried prefixing the corresponding port with localhost, 127.0.0.1, and the IP of the VM. So, I don't think it's an ipv6 issue. I've tried opening up all of those ports in the firewall. Maybe I didn't word that so well in the OP.